# Free Electrical CAD Software

Tags: gratis, cad, electronics

I am looking for free Electrical CAD software that can help me develop wiring diagrams, and diagrams containing symbols for motors, relays, lights, breakers etc.. To the best of my knowledge, schematic editors like EagleCAD and Fritzing are not very good with motors and breakers. I want to know what all free options are available. I would prefer something open-source, but it is not necessary and other kinds of software, such as commercial an freemium are also fine.

The CAD software of course should have drag and drop facility for electrical components. There should be a wide variety of Electrical components, such as fuses, breakers, motors, VFDs etc., which are not available with electronic CAD software. Allowing users to create and/or modify their own symbols would also be useful. Export as .pdf and .dwg may help too

Comment: What OS should it run on? What features do you need? Note that [we don't support list-type questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154) but rather recommend software meeting specific requirements.

Comment: I use Windows primarily, but similar software for Linux and Mac OS may be helpful for others using those OSes having similar requirements. That is the reason I did not give much attention to the OS required

Comment: Have you looked at TinyCAD? https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinycad/

Comment: I ll check it out. I thought it was for PCB and electronics layout. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try QCAD, i dont know moch about it but there is library with e-parts available http://www.ribbonsoft.com/en/qcad-add-ons . You can create, modify it...  Insertion is similar to drag and drop. If you dont need dwg support and ather features, maybe free communiti version would be enought for you. Proffesionla version for 33 Eur provide some extra features, conversion tools, dwg support etc. Check the website.